# Custom module admin Edit section became empty

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error

I created some custom module and every thing is working fine, Suddenly after uploading one more image from admin pannel in that custom module, when i refreshed my frontend page to see the effect i saw image is corrupted but some other data is coming.

When I click on edit link (`in admin side`) there is no data coming from database.

I checked database all data are saved there.

Can any one suggest what happened to the module.

There are some errors like

```
#13 /var/www/vhosts/pstest.de/homemadd.psweb.in/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/pstest.de/homemadd.psweb.in/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

in log , but one can know it is thrown by my module , as there is nothing related to my module(`like module name of my custom names that i used`)

`mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` Previous Sql

`mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php`   Upgrade Sql

I also updated `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Newssection>
            <version>0.1.1</version>  <!-- new version -->
        </Maddy_Newssection>
    </modules>
```

[image: admin_pannel]
but in edit section nothing coming
[image: NO data]

Comment: Have you checked in log file (magentoroot/var/log/*.log) there is any error there.

Comment: Check Log Files @Saurabh Ranjan

Comment: @PranayK i checked log there are some error, i updated my post

Comment: Did You change any core files @SaurabhRanjan

Comment: @PranayK No i am working in phtml page  only from last 10 minutes

Comment: But i cleared the cache , and then this bug came, i just got MySQL upgrade error that some table is already  created

Comment: @PranayK I updated my post can u plz check is there any mistake

Comment: What is Upgrade error post it please @SaurabhRanjan

Comment: @PranayK sorry i refreshed the page , On frontend every image is coming , but the error says something `custom_colmn already exists in table_name`

Comment: @but this module is uploaded 2 days back. I think is there any error in my config.xml or mysql , as this happen when i flushed cache (`by deleting var folder`)

Comment: Try to comment code in mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php and then check if working then uncomment and check.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I did as you suggested but no error , even issues still there

Comment: you can check core_resource table what is the version is updated in database. also check updated data is reflect in mysql tables. both are fine. then you can check what your updated filed is correctly called in adminhtml grid.